# How to sort yearly data?

Tags: r, sorting, date, time

I have yearly data with a "-" for the respective month. For example: 2010-1 = Jan 2010.

**When I sort my data I get the following result:**

2010 - 1

2010 - 11

2010 - 12

2010 - 2

**However, I want the following order:**

2010 - 1

2010 - 2

...

2010 - 11

2010 - 12

Comment: Take a look at `mixedsort` or `mixedorder` from the `gtools` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `yearmon` class in zoo. It internally represents year/month as year + (month - 1)/12 so that it sorts correctly and externally displays it as shown.

```
library(zoo)
x <- c("2010 - 1", "2010 - 11", "2010 - 12", "2010 - 2")

ym <- as.yearmon(x, "%Y - %m")
sort(ym)
```

giving:

```
"Jan 2010" "Feb 2010" "Nov 2010" "Dec 2010"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try:

```
df <- transform(df, Dates = format(as.Date(paste0(Dates, "-01"), "%Y-%m-%d"), "%Y-%m"))

df <- df[order(df$Dates), , drop = FALSE]
```

.. where `Dates` would be the name of your column, you can replace that with your actual column.

Output:

```
    Dates
1 2010-01
4 2010-02
2 2010-11
3 2010-12
```

Data used:

```
df <- structure(list(Dates = structure(1:4, .Label = c("2010-1", "2010-11", 
"2010-12", "2010-2"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

P.S. If your data has actual spaces within the format (like `2010 - 1`), you can do:

```
df <- transform(df, Dates = format(as.Date(paste0(Dates, " - 01"), "%Y - %m - %d"), "%Y-%m"))

df <- df[order(df$Dates), , drop = FALSE]
```